# How to fix: Delete duplicates in a JSON file and write to a new one

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with around 400.000 entries. Every entry is a city. Now I want to delete all cities which are not in Germany and then delete duplicate cities. After that I want to write the cities to a new JSON File.

For test purposes, I used the `del` method to delete the coordinates of every city. Then I created a new JSON file. Problem is, I can't even open the file, and my laptop freezes.

```py
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
import json
import string

app = Flask(__name__)

with open('cities_list/city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for cities in data['cities']:
    del cities['coord']

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Do you have an idea what went wrong?

Thank you very much!

Best wishes,
Matthias

Comment: What is the size of `city.list.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code itself. Some editors are terrible with large files, especially ones that are on a single line, as your `test.json` will end up being.

You can add `indent=2` to the `json.dump()` call to have it emit newlines and indentation (at the expense of a larger file):

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```